# How do you change Map scale interactively in Print Map Composer?

Tags: qgis, print-composer

In QGIS's Layout window there are several zoom icons a Move Item Content tool.  Is there a Zoom Item Content tool or mechanism? Or must one set the Map Item Scale explicitly in the Main Properties panel?

[image: Screenshot of QGIS print layout Move and Zoom icons]

Comment: Are you asking how to set the scale of the [map item in the item properties](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/print_composer/composer_items/composer_map.html#main-properties)?

Comment: "Map properties" has a manual entry box for scale, but I was looking for something like the layout's "zoom+" "zoom-" "zoom-window" icon tools in the screenshot, but, like the "Move item content" icon tool, would zoom on the item content instead of the layout.